# MATLAB: function point_cloud

Tags: matlab

Question:
Write a function called **point_cloud** that takes one scalar as an input argument (the function does not have to check the format of the input) and has no output argument.

If it is called like this, **point_cloud(100)**, then it plots 100 points. Each point has a random x coordinate and a random y coordinate, each of which is gotten by a call to **randn**, which uses a normal distribution with a standard deviation equal to 1. The range of the plot axes should be −5 to 5 in both the x and y dimensions. The grid should be turned off. The points should be plotted and displayed one at a time by calling **plot** with only one point specified and, following the call of plot, by a call of **drawnow**, which causes the point to be plotted immediately. The command **hold on** should be included so that all previous points are retained when a new point is plotted.

Figure 2.41 shows an example view of the plot after **point_cloud(100000)** has completed its point-by-point plotting on a Mac. (Note that on Windows the points are much larger. Also note that it takes a long time to plot this many points with **drawnow**. Finally, try zooming in the middle.)

[Figure 2.41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGhHT.png)

My Code:

```
    function point_cloud(N)

    hold on
    grid off
    axis([-5,5,-5,5])
    for ii = 1:N
        plot(randn(ii));
        drawnow;
    end
```

I know this is wrong, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Can someone help?

Solved code:

```
    function point_cloud(N)

    figure
    hold on
    grid off
    axis([-5,5,-5,5])
    x = randn(N,1);
    y = randn(N,1);
    for ii = 1:N
        plot(x(ii),y(ii),'b.');
        drawnow;
    end
```

Comment: You can type `help drawnow` at the MATLAB command prompt to read what it does and how to call it.

Comment: Okay, I edited my code, but I am not getting what is displayed in the figure. MATLAB is plotting lines instead of points.

Comment: `randn(ii)` creates an `ii`x`ii` matrix of random values. You need two of them only in each iteration (x and y). Also look into `help plot` to learn how to plot a point using its x and y coordinate. I’m not giving you the solution because I want you to learn. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved it. **See updated code above**. This code works, but I get an error when I enter `point_cloud(100000)` because the array size is too large for MATLAB. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Excellent! This is a bit counter-intuitive, but `randn(N)` doesn't generate `N` random numbers, but `N*N` (it makes a square matrix of side `N`). You want to do `randn(N,1)` instead. There should be no problem fitting  that in memory. The alternative is to generate the random numbers one by one inside the loop: `plot(randn(1),randn(1),...`.

Comment: Note sure why you want to plot each individual point separately. If you want to create an animation, you will want to use `pause(1)` than `drawnow`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the for loop at all. And drawing the plot each iteration is *very* time consuming. How about rather using the `scatter` function.

```
figure
hold on
grid off
axis([-5,5,-5,5])
x = randn(N,1);
y = randn(N,1);
scatter(x,y,'b.')
```

This will be a lot faster.

Comment: Of course it is not necessary. But if you read the question, you'll see that it is a course exercise. What the professor had in mind when writing the exercise is a different question...

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer, here is the code as a function, with the added functionality that the points are one pixel on Windows as well:

```
function point_cloud(N)
    f = figure;
    x = randn(N,1);
    y = randn(N,1);
    scatter(x,y,1/36,'b.');
    f.GraphicsSmoothing = 'off';
    grid off
    axis([-5,5,-5,5])
    axis equal
end
```

The size of the markers is set with the third parameter of scatter: 1/36. The graphics smoothing of the figure needs to be set to 'off' as well, to make sure that the pixels don't become blurry or lighter.

Here's a 3D version:

```
function point_cloud3D(N)
    f = figure;
    x = randn(N,1);
    y = randn(N,1);
    z = randn(N,1);
    scatter3(x,y,z,1/36,'b.');
    f.GraphicsSmoothing = 'off';
    grid off
    axis([-5,5,-5,5,-5,5])
    axis square
    view(3)
end
```